# How to extract the date from a string

Tags: mysql

I have saved a date as a string, Ex: `Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014`
The year is always at the end, I want to make query to get the records who has year less than a specific year, say 2012. Is this possible? How? and is it possible to fix this issue from mysql? i.e, transform the date from string to date ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MySQL [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert those values into MySQL dates:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014','%a %b %d %H:%i:%S BST %Y');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014','%a %b %d %H:%i:%S BST %Y') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-04-04 15:58:43                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's a rough example using your sample string to illustrate a query to return all rows with dates before 2012. It will require a full table scan, so it will not be fast, but it illustrates the basic concept of what you need to do:

```
select *
from your_table
where str_to_date(your_column,'%a %b %d %H:%i:%S BST %Y') < '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: Here is a big fat +1 for simplicity because I just was not thinking when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Can I change the value inside the column? I need to fix this problem permanently.

Comment: You should add a new nullable DATE column, set the values of the new column using the existing string values, then optionally drop the string column once you're not using it any more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a baseline query

```
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE('Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014'),4));
```

Here it is executed

```
mysql> SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE('Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014'),4));
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE('Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014'),4)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OMG What was I thinking ??? I was actually decoding it

```
SET @datestring = 'Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014';
SELECT CONCAT(YYYY,'-',MM,'-',DD,' ',HHMMSS) dt FROM
(SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@datestring),4)) as YYYY,
SUBSTR(FLOOR((LOCATE(LEFT(SUBSTR(@datestring,5),3),'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec')+2)/3)+100,2) MM,
SUBSTR(@datestring,9,2) DD,
SUBSTR(@datestring,12,8) HHMMSS) A;
```

and my decoding works

```
mysql> SET @datestring = 'Fri Apr 04 15:58:43 BST 2014';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(YYYY,'-',MM,'-',DD,' ',HHMMSS) dt FROM
    -> (SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@datestring),4)) as YYYY,
    -> SUBSTR(FLOOR((LOCATE(LEFT(SUBSTR(@datestring,5),3),'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec')+2)/3)+100,2) MM,
    -> SUBSTR(@datestring,9,2) DD,
    -> SUBSTR(@datestring,12,8) HHMMSS) A
    -> ;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+
| 2014-04-04 15:58:43 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted me, THANK YOU !!! @IkeWalker has the better answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639700/491757